# comapare the contents of two varibles of type uint8_t A[8] = uint8_t B

Tags: c, nxp-microcontroller

i want to comapare two values both is of type  uint8_t  A[8] =  uint8_t B   both contain the same data but one varible is continat is one block  and the other as an array

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask].  Show your code and more detail.  This question is unclear.

Comment: They can never be equal since they are different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. `A` is an array of 8 different`uint_8`s while `B` is only one value.

You can, however, compare the contents of array `A` with the following syntax:

```
A[0] == B;
A[1] == B;
...
```

Each of these returns 1 (or true) if they are equal or 0 (or false) if they are not equal.